# Import CSV issue powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I am working on a script to automate adding users. I want to read from all CSV files in a directory until they are done and then I want to move those csvs to an archive. In the program I am checking a txt file to make sure another instance of the program is not already running. after that I am allowing the code to run or the program to end. When I run the program with 1 or two test files named test.csv and test2.csv I am not having any errors. Once I add random names .csv and try to run these through I am getting the error that import-csv cannot find the file and the path is is telling me the file at it no correct, its from the location of the script.

Here is my code:

```
$fileDirectory = "c:\test";

$CheckRun = Get-Content c:\test\checkrun.txt
Write-Host $($CheckRun)

if($CheckRun -eq "notrunning") {

    Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory -Filter *.csv | Foreach-Object {
        $list= Import-Csv $_
        $State = "running"
        $basename = $_.BaseName
        $file = $FileDirectory + "\" + $basename + ".csv"
        $ArchiveFile = $fileDirectory + "\archive\" + $basename + "old.csv"
        foreach ($entry in $list) {
            # will run command here using the entries from the CSVs
            write-Host $($entry.EMAIL) $($entry.FIRSTNAME) $($entry.LASTNAME) $($entry.PASSWORD)
        }

        Move-Item $($file) ${ArchiveFile} -force

        Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

        $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
        $State > c:\test\Checkrun.txt

    }

    $State = "notrunning"
    $State > c:\test\Checkrun.txt
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
else {
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    exit
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the child items you are getting a file object. Try referenceing the fullname instead it workd for me:

```
 Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory -Filter *.csv | Foreach-Object {
        $list= Import-Csv $_.fullname
```

Otherwise it is trying to look in the path that you are running the script for the file instead of C:\test\filename.csv

Comment: That solved my problem, I could tell it was wanting to reference the file path I was running from, but I did not know the proper syntax. I also noticed the reason It worked partially is I had a copy of the first two CSVs in the same folder as the script.  Thanks,